# top position on scroll causes lag Safari/IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, safari

I trying to fix  at top position by using position:relative,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var container = $(".container");

    container.css("overflow-y", "auto");
    container.css("overflow-x", "hidden");

    container.on("scroll", function() {
        $("table", this).css("overflow-x", "hidden");
        $("th", this).css("position", "relative");
        $("th", this).css("z-index", 1);
        $("th", this).css("top", this.scrollTop + "px");
    });
});
```

an example of issues https://jsfiddle.net/hth4Ly7q/2/
it works pretty well in chrome,firefox but Safari and IE lags when scrolling, maybe someone knows how can it be fixed in safari?
I'm not using absolute/fixed positions because my real table is pretty complex to calculate widths of columns on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

I tried on Edge and IE. It looks okay.
https://jsfiddle.net/55cynfLg/

```
function setTh(){
var container = $(".container");
$("table", this).css("overflow-x", "hidden");
$("th", this).css("z-index", 1);
container.find("th").each(function(i){
  var td = container.find("tbody tr:eq(0) td:eq("+i+")");
  $(this).css({
     "width": td.width(),
     "left": td.offset().left
  });
});}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a problem I always had in Safari: you cannot solve it completely. Adding the `"mousewheel"` event will help a little bit, but it doesn't solve the problem.